# Getting the recepient count from email sent in Android

Tags: android, email

I'm launching the email program in Android from my app, using the following code...

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test subject");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World!");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Select email application."), INTENT_REQUEST_SEND_EMAIL);
```

In the called OnActivityResult(), is it possible to get the number of recepients the user has chosen to send the email to?

Thanks,
Rajath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That action does not support `startActivityForResult()`, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any other way of getting the recepient count? Any way at all.... otherwise, I assume I will have to get the contacts in the app itself and send it internally...

Comment: @Rajath: "Is there any other way of getting the recepient count?" -- not for arbitrary email apps. "otherwise, I assume I will have to get the contacts in the app itself and send it internally" -- if by "send it internally" you mean use JavaMail or something, bear in mind that this will irritate and confuse your users, since they will need to give you their email account data. Plus, you will need both the `READ_CONTACTS` and `INTERNTET` permissions, which many people will not give to you. Please adjust your requirements such that you do not need the recipient count.